# Uninstall Valgrind on OS X

Tags: valgrind, osx-elcapitan

I want to remove valgrind completely from my system. I deleted the valgrind-trunk folder that was created when I installed valgrind with brew. When I run valgrind, I get

```
valgrind: Unknown/uninstalled VG_PLATFORM 'amd64-darwin'
```

When I run `brew uninstall valgrind`, I get

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind
```

I am on El Capitan. How can I remove valgrind from my system?

Comment: What does `which valgrind` show you?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/valgrind`